# sort nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a dict in python

```
data={'d':{'2022-01-04':'completed'},'b':{'2020-12-04':'not competed'}}
```

I'd like to sort this list by date
so the result should look like this

```
data={'b':{'2020-12-04':'not competed'},'d':{'2022-01-04':'completed'}}
```

tried

```
{i:sorted(data[i].items(), key=lambda x: x[0]) for i in data}
```

but it only sort sub dict, any idea how to do this ?

Comment: You only told it to sort the sub-`dict`.

Comment: Will the sub-dict always have a single key-value pair?

Comment: In python, a `dict` doesn't have ordering. Use an `OrderedDict` or a `list` of `tuples`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite ugly, but the following seems to work:

```
data={'d': {'2022-01-04': 'completed'},
      'b': {'2020-12-04': 'not competed'}}

data = dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda pair: next(iter(pair[1]))))
list(pair[1].keys())[0]))
print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'b': {'2020-12-04': 'not competed'}, 'd': {'2022-01-04': 'completed'}}
```

Comment: Wow, nice. I was almost there but didn't get it :(

Comment: thanks a lot my friend, I have been trying it for some time, this actually works well. Answer is accepted

Comment: ikel: You're welcome. I think the trickiest part is extracting the date key from the nested dictionaries, since its value varies in each of them. The (now slightly updated) code in my answer appears to be most efficient way.